# Tracking Changes on POJO , And persisiting Changes to DB

Tags: java, versioning, pojo

I Have a ticketing System where in want to track the state changes on my Ticket Pojo. i am interested in History of what all changes were made to any property on objects of this type.

we are considering the possible options 
a) Implement DB level Triggers , which Client had Decline
b) Implement AOP advices to Track on the changes and do specific db inserts on invocation
c) Implement Custom Annotations and do the logic

But before we dive into this and start doing it, would like to know of any existing utility framework in java to do this ? and any other suggestions

Comment: And how does this pojo get modified in the first place?

Comment: By Any Means, Say for example any user comes online and performs some actions on it, or by automatic timeout or some other event occuring on it. i am trying to come up with a generic functionality to be used in similar many other type of Pojos in the app